# Difference in the meaning of two sentences

Tags: differences

> 1. I have never been with any of my exes.
> 2. I haven't had any exes.

Do the above two sentences mean exactly the same?

Comment: Assuming 'ex' to mean 'former spouse or lover', the first sentence doesn't make sense (if they are exes you must have 'been with' them at some time). The second is an odd way of expressing that you have had no previous relationships.

Answer (score 0):

No, they do not have the same meaning.

The first sentence implies that you *have* exes but perhaps haven't gone back to one. The second sentence directly says you have *no* exes.